# Oracle : Using nested query vs using mapping

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not sure if I have named this question right but the explanation may help explaining my problem to you.

I have a main table, say PROJ_MASTER consisting millions of records.
It contains columns that have codes which map to other tables for the detail of these codes, 
say PROJ_SUB_1 & PROJ_SUB_2.

What is the best way to write a query on the master table
1) mapping the columns

```
SELECT PM.SOME_COL_1,
       PM1.COL1,
       PM1.COL2
  FROM PROJ_MASTER PM, PROJ_SUB_1 PS1, PROJ_SUB_2 PS2
 WHERE PM1.COL1 = PS1.COL1
   AND PM1.COL2 = PS2.COL2
```

2) or using nested query

```
SELECT PM.SOME_COL_1,
       (SELECT DISTINCT PM1.COL1
         FROM PROJ_SUB_1 PS1
       WHERE PM.COL1 = PS1.COL1) AS COL1
       (SELECT DISTINCT PM1.COL2
         FROM PROJ_SUB_2 PS2
       WHERE PM.COL2 = PS2.COL2) AS COL2
  FROM PROJ_MASTER PM
```

I made some mistakes in using the alias(PM1 & PM2 instead of PM).

I am displaying the query plan
1st query)

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS   Cost=23827  Cardinality=1037978 Bytes=76810372
 HASH UNIQUE                Cost=23827  Cardinality=1037978 Bytes=76810372
  HASH JOIN             Cost=5638   Cardinality=1037978 Bytes=76810372
   TABLE ACCESS FULL    Object owner=USER   Object name=PROJ_MASTER 
                                    Cost=5  Cardinality=557         Bytes=17267
   HASH JOIN                Cost=5619   Cardinality=872654  Bytes=37524122
    TABLE ACCESS FULL   Object owner=USER   Object name=PROJ_SUB_1

                                    Cost=28 Cardinality=9827    Bytes=294810
    TABLE ACCESS FULL   Object owner=USER   Object name=PROJ_SUB_2

                                    Cost=5579   Cardinality=872654  Bytes=11344502
```

2nd query)

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS     Cost=9810 Cardinality=872654  Bytes=11344502
 TABLE ACCESS FULL  Object owner=USER   Object name=PROJ_SUB_1

                      Cost=5    Cardinality=1           Bytes=31
 TABLE ACCESS FULL  Object owner=USER   Object name=PROJ_SUB_2

                      Cost=28   Cardinality=1           Bytes=30
 HASH UNIQUE                  Cost=9810 Cardinality=872654  Bytes=11344502
  TABLE ACCESS FULL Object owner=USER   Object name=PROJ_MASTER 
                      Cost=5579 Cardinality=872654  Bytes=11344502
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see what `PM1` is in either of these queries, but anyway, the results of both queries is intirely different, and the second may not even work, because subqueries in this case can return at most 1 record. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide some more concrete table structure and real-life data, both source and result?

Comment: It depends on your *where clause*, *order by clause* and *grouping*. What are they in your case?

Comment: The "where" is dependent on the user input. The query supports a report and the user may enter inputs based on report view he/she wishes to see. In worst case scenario there may be minimum or none.  How will the "order" & "grouping" clause impact the query performance?

Comment: well in your first plan, the CBO is joining the detail tables together *first* which would be bizarre for the query posted (errors aside). Please post the actual query that generated this plan—there is likely a mistake in it.

Comment: also highly suspicious that `Cost=5579   Cardinality=872654  Bytes=11344502` in plan 1 for FTS on PROJ_SUB_2 and exactly the same for FTS on ***PROJ_MASTER*** in plan2, is this a cut and paste job? You'll need to be more careful if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: I made no changes the query plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases like Oracle were born to join. Your first query is the 'normal' way to do what you are trying to do, and will be fast.

Having said that, a few points:

[Most people prefer ANSI join syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618), so this will be easier to read:

```
SELECT PM.SOME_COL_1,
       COL1,
       COL2
  FROM PROJ_MASTER PM 
       JOIN PROJ_SUB_1 USING (COL1) 
       JOIN PROJ_SUB_2 USING (COL2)
```

Of course you'll probably be including some columns(s) from `PROJ_SUB_1` and `PROJ_SUB_2`.

The second query likewise should probably be selecting something from the `SUB` tables or it would be pretty pointless, but I'm assuming this is a typo. In this case, the functional difference is that:

- the query will fail if there are ever multiple matching rows (but from the question it seem natural to assume a FK relationship between the tables)
- this query is generally more verbose, slower and less readable than the first, but it has one particular property: you can see at a glance that *exactly* one row will be returned for each row in `PROJ_SUB_2` if the query succeeds, without knowing looking up the keys and relationships.

Finally, the `DISTINCT` is redundant if there really is a FK/PK relationship enforced.

Comment: Thank you Jack. That was indeed a typo mistake.  I had asked the question because I am finding the query plan of both the type of queries. The 2nd one although verbose shows less cost as compared to the 1st one. Does that mean that in the long run the 2nd query will have optimum performance

Comment: No, "Your first query is the 'normal' way to do what you are trying to do, *and will be fast.*". Do you have a minimal working example showing lower cost for the second? Perhaps a SQL Fiddle? Or post the plans you have. Incidentally, as a rule, you [can't directly compare the cost of two queries](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628). I usually use a `union all` if I want to compare.

Comment: I have added the query plans of the 2 queries for your reference. Thanks for you effort.

Answer (score 2):

The first way is the best for many reasons. It is simpler to read and understand. According to functionality and performance the first is better too. In huge amount of data you can fill the difference. It is my experience.

Comment: +1 though in edge cases like large complex queries that produce small result sets, the second method can be very handy if used sensibly.

Comment: The performance of the second query can be much better, if there are no where clause, sorting, and grouping on PM1 and PM2 columns.

Comment: Does that mean that the 2nd query in some situations can out-perform the 1st query? Please provide some details(articles, links) on these comments

Comment: @Rohan all it means is that 'it depends'. If you want a Rule Of Thumb, I've given one.